# How do you install packages from the web directory in CTAN?

Tags: packages

I wanted to install the package [`noweb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/noweb) so as usual I tried with `tlmgr install noweb` but tlmgr returned a:

> package noweb not present in package repository

Later I noticed that the `noweb` package is in a separate CTAN directory called [`web`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/web) and that all the packages in this directory cannot be installed with the standard `tlmgr` command.

So, how do I install `noweb` and other  `web` packages?

Comment: Download it and extract it on your local texmf folder.

Comment: The install guide is inside the folder [src](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/web/noweb/src) in CTAN repository and is named INSTALL.

Comment: Actually `noweb` requires also executables that need to be built for your platform. It's not available in TeX Live because it has a non-free license: “Noweb is copyright 1989-2006 by Norman Ramsey.  All rights reserved. You may use and distribute noweb for any purpose, for free.  You may modify noweb and create derived works, provided you retain the copyright notice, but the result may not be called noweb without my written consent.”

Comment: @Sigur and Klemvor So there is no automatic method using tlmgr? Do you happen to know why is that? Are these packages in any way different from the standard packages?

Comment: Nevermind, @egreg already answered my questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `noweb` bundle is a “literate programming tool” inspired by Knuth's Web. It needs executables that are provided only by some platforms (and the last build date is 2006), so probably they need to be rebuilt following the instructions.

It's not in TeX Live, so it cannot be installed with `tlmgr` because the license is non free:

> COPYRIGHT
>
> Noweb is copyright 1989-2006 by Norman Ramsey.  All rights reserved.
>
> You may use and distribute noweb for any purpose, for free.  You may
>   modify noweb and create derived works, provided you retain the
>   copyright notice, but the result may not be called noweb without my
>   written consent.  You may not sell noweb itself, but you may do
>   anything you like with programs created with noweb.

While the notice says the program is free, the way the license is written doesn't qualify it as “Free Software” in a strict sense. If you want to install and use `noweb`, you have to do it yourself.